# Is 'had have + past participle' a correct grammatical form?

Tags: grammar, tenses

It has been suggested in some quarters that *had have*, followed by a past participle, is a regionalism that has no place in standard English grammar.

*If I had have known you were coming, I would have been prepared*, or *If I'd have known you were coming, I would have been prepared*, mean essentially the same as *If I had known you were coming....*. But the former is often used for emphasis, and it sounds perfectly idiomatic to me.

So is *had have seen* etc. grammatically correct?

Comment: I have heard this form of grammar often, so I think it's a legitimate form to discuss.  In terms of grammar books, I have never seen this, so "officially" I'd say no.  Let's wait and see what some other contribute on this.

Comment: Did you see this in writing, or hear it?...Because, I cannot recall seeing it in writing.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - The are a few usage instances in Ngram, but I think it is a regional/dialectal usage.

Comment: I would parse "If I'd have known" as "If I *would* have known", not "If I *had* have known". Perhaps the latter is a backformation from the contraction, since "I'd" represents "I had" more often than "I would"?

Comment: @hobbs I'm afraid I can't agree. Unless you think the English learned their English from Americans! (Not as silly as it might sound - it sometimes happens). But  *If I would have known...* is definitely American in my view. In Britain it is *had have*.

Comment: See also: [“If I would have lost you” vs “If I had lost you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *had have* construction in an *if-clause* is an example of what is commonly called the *double perfect*. This extract from *[grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Double-Perfect.htm)* cites  *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*'s discussion of the usage, which it calls *non-standard*:

> "Instead of an ordinary preterite perfect, a non-standard 'double
> perfect' is often found:
>
> (9i) If it had've come yesterday he would surely have told her.
> (9ii) I wish he hadn't've left.
>
> This is largely restricted to speech (or the written representation of speech). It appears to be increasing in frequency, and though it is not as yet
> established as a standard form, it is used by many who in general
> speak standard English. From a grammatical point of view, it is a
> curious construction in that *had* is followed by a plain form, not a
> past participle; it is normally reduced to /əv/, and in writing is
> sometimes spelled *of*, indicating that it is not perceived as a form of
> *have*."
>
> (Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum, The Cambridge
> Grammar of the English Language, Cambridge University Press, 2002)

There's an extended discussion of the issue in [Counterfactuality in non-standard subjunctive conditionals](https://mariabiezma.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/biezma-nels43-carniesiddiqi.pdf). The authors claim that there is a semantic difference between the standard and non-standard forms. Here is their opening section which offers references to possible explanations for the '*extra piece of morphology*'.

> 1. On standard and non-standard subjunctive conditionals: The data
>
> English subjunctive conditionals can adopt different forms. The
> standard form of subjunctive conditionals (SC) is illustrated in (1).
> However, speakers of some dialects of English also accept some of the
> variants in (2) as subjunctive conditionals. The forms in (2) differ
> from (1) in that they include: *would* or *had*.
>
> (1) If Jones had taken arsenic, he would have shown some symptoms. [SC]
>
> (2) If Jones would have/ had have/ would’ve/ had’ve/ woulda’/ hada’/ would of / had of taken arsenic, he would have shown some symptoms. [NSSC]
>
> The non-standard forms (NSSC) exemplified in (2) appeared in the 15th C,
> at the time when the subjunctive voice in English disappeared
> (Huddleston & Pullum 2002). While the NSSCs mark different registers,
> no differences have been observed in terms of interpretation between
> an NSSC and an SC. The extra piece of morphology has usually been
> considered vacuous: a redundant repetition (Wilson 1993), a
> phonological harmony effect (Molencki 2000), or a psychological effect
> (Boyland 1995).
>
> The aim of this paper is two-fold: a) we present a novel empirical
> observation: we claim there is a contrast in meaning between (1) and (2); and  b) we offer an analysis that predicts the differences in meaning.

Comment: I especially like *phonological harmony* - I think this is what I was meaning in the 2nd para of my answer!

Comment: @Dan. Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English Usage refers to the construction as the _plupluperfect_, which has its own _phonological harmony_! The MWDEU contends that the construction '_may simply represent an attempt by the speaker to impose a subjunctive marker on the standard past perfect_'. This seems the most plausible explanation to me.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. It is precisely the sort of thing I was seeking, following the discussion which arose under [this OP](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289972/hadnt-have-killed-vs-hadnt-killed/289975#comment648786_289975)

Comment: If the authors of this paper would've written their conclusion in English, I would've understood it.

Answer (score 6):

***If I had have known*** sounds like a 'regional' version of ***If I had known***. The 'have' does not add any meaning as far as I can tell.  The fact that I hear '*had have*' often and even use it myself only confirms to me that it is idiomatic (and regional - Bristol UK at least) - it does not make it 'good English'!

I wonder if the usage arises simply because the construction *had have* sounds like *might have, should have, could have* etc ?

It's certainly 'out there' - [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27d%27ve&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%27d%27ve%3B%2Cc0) *I'd've*.

Comment: But *I'd've* and *I'd have* are (can be) contractions for *I **would** have*.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this form only works in a conditional phrase, typically preceded by *if*, such as this from a [UK Parliament committee (Q264)](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201012/cmselect/cmpubadm/714/11030302.htm)

> I am delighted to hear that you visited Newport and you could have
>   dropped in for a cup of tea if I had have known, and I would have
>   brought you up to date that it is no longer called the Patent Office

but even there *had known* would work as well as *had have known*.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what tense is **had have + past participle'**
As what I know, it should be '**Had + past participle of the verb'**

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, Erlyn. If you read Shoe's answer, you'll see the standard of response ELU hopes will be provided.

Answer (score -1):

verbix.com has the conjugation tables of standard English in the best form.
See table for to do [here](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/Do.html)

Of course, there may be regional variants, but they aren't standard English.

Only in past perfect "had" (past tense) is followed by a second verb form, and that is "had"(past participle). An infinitive is not possible.