# Conditional structure – “hadn't have gone”? “hadn't have met”?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

Recently I saw two interviews, one with Victoria Beckham, the other one with Elton John. They were talking about their past experiences and that's the phrasing they used:

> But it wouldn't have happened if we HADN'T HAVE GONE to the Ukraine. (Elton)
>
> And I probably would still be that way if I HADN'T HAVE MET the girls. (Victoria)

Is there any explanation behind the grammar written in capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

This double perfect is common in spoken English but not as yet taught as correct, please follow this link to a previous answer.

([Is 'had have + past participle' a correct grammatical form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290111/is-had-have-past-participle-a-correct-grammatical-form#290127))

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged here but on the other hand you did find a very relevant post that should help the OP, so +1